# Using Silverlight with Existing Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, silverlight-3.0

This seems like a very basic question but I couldn't find any help on web. If you could provide some link or steps to do this.

I have created few basic Silverlight applications which are working fine standalone. I also have a basic ASP.NET application with a solution with around 10 Class Library Projects and 1 website. I want to create a small popup which will have some functionality using Silverlight.

How should I go about creating this application and how to integrate it with my existing application for it to show as a link. I would not want that link to open another application/site.

Comment: You want Show Your Silverlight App in a PopUp, if someone klick a Hyperlink?

Comment: Yes sort of. That's where I want to start. But, I want to know in general how to create any module in Silverlight and add to existing website or web application.

Comment: Silverlight is just an object on an html page. You would add it just like you add any other HTML object to the page.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I am trying to add few of the basic controls from ToolKit and facing lot of problems. Probably will be opening a separate question for that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here:

http://felix.pastebin.com/bFgkUxSd

Werewolve